# How do I run tasks in parallel and select the first result that satisfies a given condition in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, wait

There are three tasks that I wish to run in parallel. I wish to examine the result of the first task that finished and do a check to decide if the result is *good*. If yes, I cancel all other tasks and return this result, if not, I will wait for next completed task and check if that is *good* and do the same if it is. (Think of being *good* as some simple check on a member of OutputDataType).

I continue this until I obtain a completed task with a *good* result, or all tasks return with results that are not *good*, in which case I return `null`.

Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            InputDataType data = getMyData();
            OutputDataType x = Foo(data);
        }   

        static OutputDataType Foo(InputDataType data)
        {
            Task<OutputDataType> task1 = null, task2 = null, taks3 = null;
            Task<OutPutDataType>[] TaskArray = { task1, task2, task3 };

            task1 = Task<SolutionInterpreters>.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc1(data));
            task2 = Task<SolutionInterpreters>.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc2(data));
            task3 = Task<SolutionInterpreters>.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc3(data));

            /*
            .
            .
            .
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TPL, task cancellation is cooperative, so you need to define some means of indicating to your other tasks that they should stop executing. The most common way to do this is through `CancellationTokenSource`, whose token can be checked for cancellation within your `RunFuncX` methods.

```
static void Main()
{
    InputDataType data = getMyData();
    OutputDataType x = Foo(data).Result;
}   

static async Task<OutputDataType> Foo(InputDataType data)
{
    // Spawn your tasks, passing the cancellation token.
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc1(data, cts.Token));
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc2(data, cts.Token));
    var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunFunc3(data, cts.Token));
    var tasks = new [] { task1, task2, task3 };

    // Loop while tasks are running.
    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        // Wait for any task to complete.
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        // If its result is good, indicate cancellation to the other tasks,
        // and return the result.
        if (IsResultGood(completedTask.Result))
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            return completedTask.Result;
        }

        // Otherwise, remove the completed task from the array,
        // and proceed to the next iteration.
        tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != completedTask).ToArray();
    }

    // No good results.
    return null;
}
```

Per Spo1ler's comment, I've updated your `Foo` method to an asynchronous implementation. This assumes you're using C# 5.0. When consuming the method, use `await` to get its result. If you're really running as a console application, your topmost call would need to block, so you can just get the task's `Result`.

Comment: But this code will block. Wound't it be better from performance standpoint to use `Task.WhenAny` and make it use thread pool more effectively?

Comment: @Spo1ler: Good point. I've updated my code to an asynchronous implementation.